# Prebid.js Uncaught ReferenceError: pbjs is not defined

Tags: javascript, prebid.js, uncaught-reference-error

Despite including Prebid.js we are still getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: pbjs is not defined. https://testdomaininads.ml for full page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's defined for me on the site now. You may need to disable your adblocker because the prebid4.38.0.js file is blocked (in case you have one installed).